# I want to insert multiple email in one single column with # separated

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert multiple email addresses into one single column in database, separated by a `#`

I have using three input fields like this:

```
 email : <input type="text"name="email">
 email : <input type="text"name="email">
 email : <input type="text"name="email">**
```

and I want to database fields like this:

```
vks155@gmail.com # vks155@gmail.com # vks155@gmail.com #
```

My mysql query

```
$query = mysql_query("insert into table1 (email) values(email) ");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
HTML:
email : <input type="text" name="email[]">
email : <input type="text" name="email[]">
email : <input type="text" name="email[]">

PHP:
$email = implode(' # ', $_POST['email']);
$query=mysql_query("insert into table1 (email) values('{$email}) ");
```

This assumes that you're using `method=post` in the form tag.

Please be aware that there are no security measures in the above code, you will want to escape the POST input.

Also, you should probably use `<input type=email>` these days.

Comment: thank you vary much matt